# localStorage and Greater than and Less Than with Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slider and I want to make it so that on a button press -

If a variable (rangeValue) has a value of 1-50, then another variable (chanceofdeath) has a value of 1.

If a variable(rangeValue) has a value of 51-100, then another variable (chanceofdeath) has a value of 2.

This is what I have:https://jsfiddle.net/kzyffz9v/2/

Although, it prints NaN in the paragraph. Is it a problem with `localStorage`, or the greater than and less than statements? Please correct my code.

Comment: You don't have `chanceofdeath` set in localStorage, so when you call `localStorage.getItem`, it returns null. Then, you call parseInt(null) which gives you NaN, you can give a default value to `chanceOfDeath` to avoid this problem `parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceofdeath")) || 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the value initialization to the function, instead of using in inline event handler.

Also make sure you are setting the variable in local storage.

**HTML**

```
onchange="my2Function()">
```

**JS**

```
function my2Function(){

    var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);

    if (rangeValue < 50 && x > 0){
        chanceofdeath +=1;
    }
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzyffz9v/4/)**

**Edit**

```
localStorage.setItem("chanceofdeath", 23);
var chanceofdeath = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceofdeath"), 10);
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var submitElement = document.querySelector('.submit');
var x = 2;

submitElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = chanceofdeath;
  localStorage.setItem("chanceofdeath", chanceofdeath);
});

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  chanceofdeath = chanceofdeath || 0;
  if (rangeValue < 50 && x > 0) {
    chanceofdeath += 1;
  }
  if (rangeValue < 100 && x > 49) {
    chanceofdeath += 2;
  }
});
```

**[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzyffz9v/10/)**

Comment: Why does it print 24 or 23 when you drag the slider? I also want it to activate onclick.

Comment: Why is var x there?

Comment: How do you make it activate onclick?

Comment: Don't you need to use localVariable.getItem at the beginning and localVariable.setItem at the end?

Comment: What would you do on the radio buttons page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131266/discussion-between-nathan-chan-and-sushanth).